# Output of caret train using multinom() and assessing model stability

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to build a multinomial logistic regression model to predict classes. To make sure that the model's predictive ability does not deviate with new data, I tried using the repeated cross-validation procedure via the `caret` package. I am not able to understand how I should interpret the output. The data I have is pretty large so, for the purpose of reproducibility, I have used the `iris` data set as an example. The code is as follows

```
library(caret)
library(nnet)

iris_data <- iris

## Base Class against which log odds are calculated
iris_data$Species <- relevel(iris_data$Species,ref='setosa')
train_control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv',number=10,repeats = 10,verboseIter = TRUE)

model_cv <- caret::train(Species~.,data=iris_data,trControl=train_control,
                         method='multinom')
```

The above code results in 100 iterations of cross-validation(10 fold cross validation repeated 10 times) and the following are one of the outputs.

```
- Fold10.Rep10: decay=1e-04 
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting decay = 0.1 on full training set
# weights:  18 (10 variable)
initial  value 164.791843 
iter  10 value 29.291910
iter  20 value 26.055889
iter  30 value 26.039352
iter  30 value 26.039352
iter  30 value 26.039352
final  value 26.039352 
converged
```

I am not able to understand what the output `value` means. Is this residual deviance?

**Model Stability**

And to assess the stability of the model I used the command `model_cv$resample` which gave me the following result.(truncated). Should model stability be assessed by looking at the deviation in the Accuracy scores? Or am I missing out on a key functionality in `caret`? Thank You in advance!

```
    Accuracy Kappa     Resample
1  0.9333333   0.9 Fold04.Rep02
2  1.0000000   1.0 Fold03.Rep02
3  0.9333333   0.9 Fold02.Rep02
4  0.9333333   0.9 Fold05.Rep02
5  1.0000000   1.0 Fold01.Rep02
6  1.0000000   1.0 Fold10.Rep01
7  1.0000000   1.0 Fold06.Rep02
8  1.0000000   1.0 Fold03.Rep01
9  1.0000000   1.0 Fold08.Rep01
10 1.0000000   1.0 Fold07.Rep02
```

Comment: `method='multinom'` in `caret` actually fits a neural network. One of the hyper parameters for this algorithm is `decay`. By default caret uses a random search of length three and chooses the best hyper parameter combination based on mean re-sampled performance. By default when doing classification the measure used to assess model performance is  Accuracy which in many cases is not what one is trying to optimize. Caret has excellent tutorials http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html.

Comment: Thanks for this! I should have used the `mlogit::mlogit()` function.